# str_replace() html entities characters

Tags: php, html, str-replace, html-entities

I create this script to convert only characters (not symbols).

Basically, i create two arrays:

**First one:**

```
$decode = array("À","Á","Â","Ã","Ä","Å","Æ","Ç","È","É","Ê","Ë","Ì","Í","Î","Ï","Ð","Ñ","Ò","Ó","Ô","Õ","Ö","Ø","Ù","Ú","Û","Ü","Ý","Þ","ß","à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ð","ñ","ò","ó","ô","õ","ö","ø","ù","ú","û","ü","ý","þ","ÿ");
```

**Second one(entities):**

```
$entities = array("&Agrave;","&Aacute;","&Acirc;","&Atilde;","&Auml;","&Aring;","&AElig;","&Ccedil;","&Egrave;","&Eacute;","&Ecirc;","&Euml;","&Igrave;","&Iacute;","&Icirc;","&Iuml;","&ETH;","&Ntilde;","&Ograve;","&Oacute;","&Ocirc;","&Otilde;","&Ouml;","&Oslash;","&Ugrave;","&Uacute;","&Ucirc;","&Uuml;","&Yacute;","&THORN;","&szlig;","&agrave;","&aacute;","&acirc;","&atilde;","&auml;","&aring;","&aelig;","&ccedil;","&egrave;","&eacute;","&ecirc;","&euml;","&igrave;","&iacute;","&icirc;","&iuml;","&eth;","&ntilde;","&ograve;","&oacute;","&ocirc;","&otilde;","&ouml;","&oslash;","&ugrave;","&uacute;","&ucirc;","&uuml;","&yacute;","&thorn;","&yuml;");
```

And REPLACE with `str_replace($entities, $decode, $string)` .

Apparently it should work, but for example with this string.

```
$string= "&Atilde;&uml; &Atilde;&sup2; &Atilde;&nbsp; &Atilde;&sect; &Atilde;&sup1; &Acirc;&sect; &Acirc;&deg; *&Atilde;&copy;";
```

Return

```
Ãƒ¨ Ãƒ² Ãƒ  Ãƒ§ Ãƒ¹ Ã‚§ Ã‚° *Ãƒ©
```

I can not understand why it does not work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `str_replace($decode, $entities, $string);`

Answer (score 0):

That's odd.  When I run your code I get this output.

```
Ã¨ Ã² Ã  Ã§ Ã¹ Â§ Â° *Ã©
```

Tell me a bit more about your setup e.g. the version of PHP you're testing on, Web Server (Apache?) and version and where you're testing the output e.g. command line or browser (Which browser?).

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> setted, PHP v5.3.21, Apache, Chrome. That's it ;)

Comment: Yeah I literally copied your arrays, test string and the str_replace function and I  received the output above which I assume is the correct output?  Try testing your code [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)